# Meta-refresh doesnt work on mozilla and IE

Tags: html, meta

I have a page and I refresh it every x second to find something in the data base, when it find i want to redirect to another page.

and im using this to redirect my page:

```
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=1;url='login.html'>";
```

But this doesn't work on mozilla neither in IE.

Anyone can help me? (If you need any other information for help me I can provide)

Comment: https://validator.nu/

Comment: check your syntax, the `content` value is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta the HTML you're looking for is:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/bn/login.html">
```

which will redirect a user to `http://website.com/login.html` after 1 second.

The important updates are where the quotes are for the `content` attribute, as well as having a full URL for the `url=` part of the instruction.

Echoing this in PHP would be nearly identical:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/bn/login.html">';
```

Comment: echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=http://localhost/bn/login.html'>";       stays like this? Or am I making a lot of confusion?

Comment: @Jorge sorry, didn't see your update using PHP. `localhost` still needs `http://`, so you'd do `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/bn/login.html">';` I updated my answer to reflect this.